# Android Studio Google Play Service issue

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am having problem in Android Studio when I tried to import a project I am facing the following problem:

> - Project
>     Laste-Android-master:/Users/Mac/Documents/Projects/Laste-Android-master/project.properties:
>     Library reference
>     ../../../../Library/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
>     could not be found Path is
>     /Users/Mac/Documents/Projects/Laste-Android-master/../../../../Library/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
>     which resolves to
>     /Users/Library/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

I am having Google Play Services installed, still I am getting this problem, can someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you clean your project?

Comment: Actually I had the Android SDK in downloads folder, but the application looked under Library folder, thats the reason error came, after changing the folder path it worked correctly